# HTML/CSS Basic table styling

Tags: html, css, html-table

This table isn't showing it's styles whenever I add text to the `<td>` here:

```
<td rowspan="3">
30th May 2014 17:35...
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
<style type="text/css">
.tftable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 5px;border-color: #9dcc7a;}

.tftable th {font-size:12px;background-color:#abd28e;border-width: 5px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #9dcc7a;text-align:center;}

.tftable tr {background-color:#ffffff;}

.tftable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 5px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #9dcc7a;}

</style>
<table class="tftable" border="5">
<tr>
<th>Super Tips Max Selections</th>
<th>Special Bonus</th>
<th>Preformance Graph And History</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">
30th May 2014 17:35 Newcastle It's All A Game
30th May 2014 18:15 Tramore Trazar
30th May 2014 20:30 Down Royal Toccata Blue
30th May 2014 20:55 Stratford Ullswater</td>
<td>Row:1 Cell:2</td>
<td rowspan="3"><img align="right" width="440" src="https://docs.google.com/a/systemlays.co.uk/spreadsheet/oimg?key=0Al8zqdk2bymPdHBhRDg1cENHUU9JX2VQSmlOX2NRdWc&oid=1&zx=x0i7dkkt7k3l" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row:2 Cell:2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row:3 Cell:2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You say the style for `.tftable td` is not applied? I think it is.

Comment: whats not styled...? http://jsfiddle.net/7YzK8/

Comment: Looks OK to me: http://jsfiddle.net/Wb6Aa/  Which styles aren't being applied?

Comment: @user3573128 Looks fine to me... Is the table a `<div class="">` by any chance?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). And in any case, "thanks in advanced" is meaningless in English.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS style is perfectly alright. What is it which you think is not working right?
You may want to try showing

> '30th May 2014 17:35 Newcastle It's All A Game 30th May 2014 18:15
>   Tramore Trazar 30th May 2014 20:30 Down Royal Toccata Blue 30th May
>   2014 20:55 Stratford Ullswater'

in different lines, you can use line break br or even table for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting your `<style></style>` tags inside of your `<head></head>` tags.

[W3 Schools: Style Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp)

Comment: Better yet, use an external style sheet if possible.

Answer (score 0):

@user3573128 it seems like your issue is solved, is it? Let us know if you are facing any further challenge in completing this. It is always better to put your style in head tag and place your js at the bottom of the page. This speedups DOM load.